# Polynomials with variables as exponent

Tags: variables, sage, exponent, polynomials

I'm using

```
R=QQ['x'];
```

to declare `x` as variable such that I can calculate with polynomials in `x`. What I need is another variable, for example `t`, to represent an integer which can also be used as exponent. For example I want to consider the polynomial (t+1)x^t. Is that somehow possible in SageMath?

**EDIT:** I want to explain a little bit the reason why I'm looking for such a feature. I've got a couple of really complex rational functions in a few variables and want SageMath to help me to show that they are identical. They are written down in a different way and if you would do it with pen and paper you would need hours and have a huge change of making mistakes. Actually it are not only a few rational functions but infinitely many. But using variables in the coefficients you can cover infinitely many with only one rational function. A simple example is the polynomial 1+x+x^2+...+x^t. For every non-negative integer you get a different polynomial. But you can write (x^(t+1)-1)/(x-1) as rational function instead. With taking `t` as a variable you cover infinitely many cases with just one rational function.

Is there a way to do such stuff in SageMath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the polynomial x^t as an element of a polynomial ring, Sage needs to know what integer t is equal to. If polynomials of undetermined degree were introduced, most of the Sage methods for polynomials would not work for them: no way to get the list of coefficients with `coefficients()`, or to find the factors, or the GCD of two polynomials, etc.

However, you can manipulate and simplify polynomials and rational functions just like any other symbolic expressions. For example:

```
x,t,k = var('x,t,k')
sum(x^k, k, 1, t)
```

returns `(x^(t + 1) - x)/(x - 1)`.

The relevant articles are [Symbolic Computation](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/calculus/calculus.html) and [Symbolic Expressions](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/symbolic/expression.html).

Comment: I explained in my edit why I want to do that. Maybe you have a different solution for me.

Comment: I expanded my answer accordingly.